# Upgraded to new Admob, income history of apps back to 0?

Tags: admob

I upgraded to the new Admob and all my payment information for my apps have now disappeared, the apps are there but admob is claiming I have 0 impressions for the apps and no money has been made (despite old admob saying there was a bit of money there).

What gives?

Comment: Wouldnt this be a better question for admobs support? This isnt really programming related.

Comment: Admob support? That doesn't actually exist, and if it does Google does everything it can to hide it...

Comment: If you go to [this page on their support site](https://support.google.com/admob/v2/troubleshooter/3178457?hl=en&ref_topic=3176518), it has an option to find out about why you cant see earnings from your old account after upgrading.